# Cloudenity certificate bound access token request sample

Tags: mtls

I am learning how to use mtls with IDPs and the one I am testing now is Cloudenity.

I've followed their [doc](https://cloudentity.com/developers/basics/oauth-client-authentication/oauth-mtls-client-authentication/?q=tls_client_auth) to configure the application.

When I tried to send the request to the token endpoint, I am getting 400 response

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url https://xxx.authz.cloudentity.io/xxx/oauth2/token \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials \
  --data client_id=xxx \
  --cacert ca.pem \
  --cert cert.pem \
  --key key.pem

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed","error_hint":"client must provide x509 certificate","status_code":400}
```

When I tried this command with `-v` flag, it seems that I am going through cloudflare. From my understanding, mTLS must happen between the server and client directly, which means this will never work when a proxy is in between.

Does anyone know how this works? Can you please give me an example?

Thank you